# Laravel 7 ReflectionException in different name route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

This question may seem silly for expert Laravel developer. However, I am facing difficulties to solve this problem. The scenario is like :
I have the following two methods with the same code in a controller.

- create(): **working fine**
- index(): ReflectionException
  Class App\Http\Controllers\Item does not exist
  http://localhost/laravel-test/public/employee-infos/index

I don't find any reason why the method index() not working as expected with the same code (code screenshot attached).
[image]
Help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer update

Comment: have tried with your solution. but still the problem persists.